# Do all the angles change in cyclopropane and cyclobutane or it is only the C-C-C angles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

Are the angles other than the C-C-C angles in cyclopropane and cyclobutane still 109.5° as the acyclic compound, or what?

Answer (score 2):

The other bond angles can't all be $109.5°$ if the angles in the ring are different from that.  Bond angles around an atom are not independent variables because the amount of space to be spanned is fixed.